# Динамическое добавление нового узла в DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Я хочу динамически добавить узел, которого нет в DOM, без использования внешних библиотек. Вот HTML код:

```js
function b1_onclick() {
  let d = document.createElement('div');
  let v = document.i1.value;
  d.innerHTML = "<h1>Введено значение ${v}</h1>";
  document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>C5Task3</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="i1">
  <button type="button" id="b1">Отправить</button>
  <div id="d1"></div>
  <script src="C5Task3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Предполагается, что по нажатию кнопки под элементом  должен появиться блок ,содержащий внутри HTML-код. И всё это должно отобразиться в окне браузера.

У меня блок div с html-кодом не появляется. Скажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Функция то запускается? По каду не видно, как вы установили обработчик нажатия на кнопку

Comment: Ну. во-первых, `document.getElementById('i1').value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас была ошибка в определении value, а так же для формирования строки с ${} нужны обратные кавычки

```js
function b1_onclick() {
  let d = document.createElement('div');
  let v = document.getElementById('i1').value; // Выбираем элемент и его значение
  d.innerHTML = `<h1>Введено значение ${v}</h1>`; // Формируем строку
  document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="i1">
<button type="button" id="b1" onclick="b1_onclick()">Отправить</button>
<div id="d1"></div>
```

P.S.: Обработчик нажатия повесил в атрибуте onclick кнопки. Вы можете поставить обработчик любым другим способом на ваше усмотрение

Comment: про добавление обработчика не сказал ничего

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!