# Как отобразить ту же html страницу и данные json используя ajax запрос?

Tags: html, django, json, ajax

Заранее благодарю всех за комментарии. Я только осваиваю ajax c django. Буду рада дельному совету.

Файл 1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<!-- КАКОЙ-ТО КНТЕНТ-->

<div id="alert">АЛЕРТ</div>

<form method='POST'>
      {% csrf_token %}
<button id="btn" class="btn" type='submit'> Check </button>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

      $.ajax(
    {
        type:"POST",
        url: "{% url 'exists' %}",
        headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
        },
        cache: true,
        dataType : "json",// Какой тип здесь указать?
        success: function(response){
            $("#alert").text('УРААА');// Как вместо УРААА добавить JSON данные
        },
        error: function(response){
            $("#alert").text('Не работает');
        },
     })
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Файл views.py (фрагмент)

```
def exView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = {"имя1": "Светлана", "имя2": "Виктория",} // Это заглушка, на самом деле здесь другие данные, но структура та же
        return render(request, 'NewApp/1.html', {'data': data})
    else:
        return render(request, 'NewApp/1.html', )
```

Файл urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from NewApp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.exView, name='exists'),
]
```

Comment: Что значит - вывести ту же страницу? Какого поведения вы хотите достичь?

Comment: Добрый день. Отобразить, рендерить. Если подробнее, но внизу страницы будут данные (сверху какой-то контент), которые будут подгружаться на эту же страницу при нажатии на кнопку, контент сверху должен осаваться неизменным.

Comment: Что при этом будет приходить в ответе? Готовый HTML или только данные? Хотя в любом случае, логика будет следующей: Получить данные, выбрать на странице нужный узел DOM и в него вставить полученные данные. Либо готовый HTML, то можно воспользоваться методом innerHTML или insertAdjacentHTML. Если только данные, то сначала структуру HTML надо будет создать силами JS, а потом уже вставлять в DOM.

Comment: В ответе будут приходить только json данные. Спасибо за ваш ответ. HTML уже существует, не совсем понимаю, что значит создать HTML силами js,

Comment: Посмотрите примеры [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1561256/1561258#1561258) [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461333/1462176#1462176) или [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1533438/1533441#1533441). В примерах есть и селекторы и примеры, как формировать HTML силами JS, как его потом вставить в DOM

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать. Уточняю свой вопрос. Мне требуется добавить вместо вывода УРААА json данные, которые передаются (формируются?)  из view. В общем буду разбираться дальше.

Comment: То что будет приходить с бэка, будет лежать в переменной response. в методе как раз вызывайте фукнцию рисования новых данных и передавайте ваш response. Ну и от jQuery можно отказаться в пользу обычного js